# Frameworks using Redis

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, programming-languages, redis

I would like to know if there are any MVC framework compatible with Redis as a database. (Not just as a caching datastore).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby you can use [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/) as ORM. If you want an MVC framework, it can be plugged to [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/).

Comment: FOr Python world there is redisco which is inspired by ohm.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Padrino is a MVC framework. It can be used with Ohm, an ORM which uses Redis as database.

Answer (score 4):

+1 for Padrino.

Another great option is [Monk](https://github.com/monkrb/monk). It includes [Ohm](https://github.com/soveran/ohm)(its actually written by some of the same guys) and is based on Sinatra. Its really easy to get started with and very flexible.

Answer (score 3):

I would not expect any MVC framework to be tied to a database. Your implementation of the Model would provide access to whatever backing store (either directly or via one or more layers) was appropriate. You should be looking at the [clients](http://redis.io/clients) that Redis supports, with those you should be able to utilise MVC frameworks on any of the support client platforms.

Answer (score 1):

try to investigate [cqrs architecture with event sourcing](http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/). 
And you can download example of this from [github](https://github.com/cavalle/banksimplistic).it is Ruby on Rails application with Redis DB

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out my C# ServiceStack.Redis Client. The client provides a typed API that can store any type and other high-level functionality, i.e. Strong-typed messaging API, Transactional Support, Pipelining, etc.

Here's is an mini [clone of Stack Overflow](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisStackOverflow/) built with it, using [only one page of C#](https://github.com/mythz/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs):

Sample Code from Redis StackOverflow:

```
public User GetOrCreateUser(User user)
{
    if (user.DisplayName.IsNullOrEmpty())
        throw new ArgumentNullException("DisplayName");

    var userIdAliasKey = "id:User:DisplayName:" + user.DisplayName.ToLower();

    using (var redis = RedisManager.GetClient())
    {
        //Get a typed version of redis client that works with <User>
        var redisUsers = redis.As<User>();

        //Find user by DisplayName if exists
        var userKey = redis.GetValue(userIdAliasKey);
        if (userKey != null)
            return redisUsers.GetValue(userKey);

        //Generate Id for New User
        if (user.Id == default(long))
            user.Id = redisUsers.GetNextSequence();

        redisUsers.Store(user);

        //Save reference to User key using the DisplayName alias
        redis.SetEntry(userIdAliasKey, user.CreateUrn());

        return redisUsers.GetById(user.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, its actually instant when its run locally :) so the latency you see is the network. Funny thing is that its fast despite each click making *3* web service calls and over 30+ #redis operations!

Answer (score 0):

grails has redis support in GORM through the redis plugin.  Any domain class can be stored in redis (or any one of the other supported nosql stores) instead of a relational database.